# vuejs unit testing, default installation says no test specified

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, vue.js, babeljs

On Windows 7. Installed a fresh vue project using the VueJS UI utility. Set unit testing / Jest enabled. Added babel.

running "npm test" at the command line returns `'Error: no test specified'`.

I have the typical `"scripts": { "vue-cli-service test:unit" }` set up in my package.json file.

jest.config.js has the expected matching pattern:

```
{  testMatch: [
    '**/tests/unit/**/*.spec.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)|**/__tests__/*.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)'
  ] }
```

So, it's not finding even the example file located in tests/unit/example.spec.js.

Curiously, I CAN get it to find tests I run directly from the node_modules directory, using `vue-cli-service`:

```
node_modules\.bin\vue-cli-service test:unit
```

from there I get a babel transpile problem (it fails to recognize the ES6 `import` command in the `example.spec.js` file) .. which is another nightmare, perhaps not for this post.

Tried updating npm (using `6.9.2`). Vue cli version is `3.8.2`. Tried deleting the node_modules directory. 
Any help is most appreciated.

After running `npm test`, the error looks like this:

```
> testing_research@0.1.0 test C:\Users\allan.luchenitser\sandbox\testing_research
> echo 'Error: no test specified'

'Error: no test specified'
```

thanks again,

Answer (score 1):

Your `package.json`'s `"scripts"` should contain a named script. Example:

```
"scripts": {
  // other scripts...
  "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit"
}
```

In addition, you have to configure `jest` to parse any `.js` or `.ts` test files in your project, adding this configuration to your `package.json`:

```
"jest": {
  "moduleFileExtensions": [
    "js",
    "ts",
    "json",
    "vue"
  ],
  "transform": {
    ".*\\.(vue)$": "vue-jest"
  }
}
```

Now running `npm run test:unit` should find and run any tests you have in your project.